How to create global error handler in next js for API?
I  created a function for handling the error but I have to pass this function to every try-catch block of the API. How can I avoid that? Is there a better  way to handle API errors in NextJS?
The function which I created, please suggest any doc or example
const errorHandler = (err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
  // console.log("err",err);
  const responseMessage = isDevelopment ? `invalid request ${err.message}` : 'Something went wrong';
  return res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: false,
    message: responseMessage,
  });
};


module.exports = errorHandler;


If you already use axios, you could use axios.interceptor which intercept all request to API so that you can adjust your function.
https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors
ex)
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      // 401 Unauthorized error handlong
    } else if (error.response && error.response.status === 404) {
      // 404 Not Found error handling
    } else if (error.response && error.response.status === 500) {
      // 500 Internal Server Error handling
    } else {
      // ETC
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

If you don't want to use axios, there's also Next.js built-in feature called 'middleware' which do the similar thing(intercept all request to specific API endpoint you want or to ALL).
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware

hi i appreciate your answer, I want to handle error of api in server side.  this middleware and axios intercepter is use for validate api in client side i want to handle error globally in server side in next js

@vyomchaudhary Then, how about implementing wrapper function? You can do it yourself, or check libraries something like this 'https://github.com/rexfordessilfie/nextwrappers'.
